# indexed query, but still searching every row

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization, rows, explain

I have the following mysql query

```
select points_for_user from items where user_id = '38415';
```

explain on the query returns this

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key                     key_len ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      items   index   NULL            points_for_user_index   2       NULL    1000511 Using index
```

The problem is, shouldn't the number of rows be FAR less then the number of rows in the table because of the index?

user_id is the primary index, so I tried creating an index on just points_for_user and that still look through every row. An index on user_id AND points_for_user still searches every row.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
  `capture_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `creator_user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `accuracy` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `captured_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '2011-01-01 06:00:00',
  `ip` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `capture_type_id` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `points` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '5',
  `points_for_user` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '3',
  PRIMARY KEY (`capture_id`),
  KEY `capture_user` (`capture_id`,`id`,`user_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`,`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `capture_creator_index` (`capture_id`,`creator_user_id`),
  KEY `points_capture_index` (`points_for_user`,`creator_user_id`),
  KEY `points_for_user_index` (`points_for_user`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1008992 ;
```

---

```
select count(*) from items where user_id = '38415'

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  captures    ref user_munzee_id  user_munzee_id  4   const   81  Using index
```

Comment: Is it a composite index? Why do you specify number in quotes?

Comment: yes, the index on points_for_user and user_id was a composite index. i'm not sure what you mean by quotes. Does that matter if I use '38415' as opposed to just 38415?

Comment: Well, if ID is a numerical column it will be indexed as such, and you're specifying a string to search for instead.

Comment: @Scott Foster: I've seen in my practice when quotes around numbers triggered implicit cast of the field values. So - yes, specifying a number as a string may cause some strange behaviour

Comment: That didn't change the rows examined if I did it in quotes or not.

Comment: Post your table structure - something doesn't make sense. Among other things the `type` should be `const`.

Comment: What is the result for `select count(*) from items where user_id = '38415'`?

Comment: Just guessing here, but if you were willing to change the ip column to a fixed-width, you might get acceptable (even impressive) performance without so many indexes... I find that sometimes too many indexes can confuse the query plan, and that non-indexed queries can be highly performant if there are not variable-width columns in the table.

Comment: If you haven't ever run `analyze_table`, your problem is likely that the table stats are out of date and causing the optimizer to make bad choices, such as a full-index-scan on a million-row index.

Comment: @Scott Just a side note, but you really need to stop using single quotes when referencing integers! In both queries that you posted you did that, and it's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the mysql optimizer try to use the best possible index during the query.

In your first query the optimizer is considering points_for_user_index the best choice, in fact the Extra column show the "Using index" status, this means a "Covering index".

The "Covering index" occurs when all fields required for a query (in your case select points_for_user from ... )  are contained in an index, this avoid the access to the full mysql data (.MYD) in favour of the direct index access (.MYI)

First of all you can try to rebuild the index tree analyzing table

> ANALYZE TABLE itemes;

**Note for very large tables**:

> ANALYZE TABLE analyzes and stores the key distribution for a table.
>   During the analysis, the table is locked with a read lock for InnoDB
>   and MyISAM. This statement works with InnoDB, NDB, and MyISAM tables.
>   For MyISAM tables, this statement is equivalent to using myisamchk
>   --analyze.

If "the problem" persist and you want to bypass the optimizer choice you can explicit try to force the usage of an index

```
EXPLAIN SELECT points_for_user FROM items USE INDEX ( user_id ) WHERE user_id = '38415'
```

More details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-hints.html

Cristian

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After running ANALYZE and forcing the index, I still get rows > 1000511 when I should only get a few hundred. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you post the explain results using the "USE INDEX" and the output of "SHOW INDEXES table items"?

Comment: I removed all of the indexes except the primary one, and slowly added new ones using EXPLAIN and that worked very well to ensure they were doing their job.